# python bitbucket unable to fetch repository (False, 'Service not found.')

Tags: python, bitbucket

I am using bitbucket library of python. I got service not found while I am fetching a public repo. As  mentioned [here](https://bitbucket-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html)

```
>>> from bitbucket.bitbucket import Bitbucket
>>> bb = Bitbucket('aaaa44@gmail.com', repo_name_or_slug = 'test')
>>> bb.repository.get()
(False, 'Service not found.')
```

Repo is exists .

Also I tried the below one

```
>>> from bitbucket.bitbucket import Bitbucket
>>> bb = Bitbucket(USERNAME, PASSWORD, 'private_slug')
>>> success, result = bb.repository.get()
```

But same error

(False, 'Service not found.')

It only work when I do

```
bb.repository.all()

(True, [{u'scm': u'git', u'has_wiki': False, u'last_updated': u'2018-05-26T05:47:37.604', u'no_forks': False, u'created_on': u'2018-05-26T05:43:42.279', u'owner': u'hari11', u'logo': u'https://bitbucket.org/hari11/test/avatar/32/?ts=1527306457', u'email_mailinglist': u'', u'is_mq': False, u'size': 58848, u'read_only': False, u'fork_of': None, u'mq_of': None, u'state': u'available', u'utc_created_on': u'2018-05-26 03:43:42+00:00', u'website': u'', u'description': u'', u'has_issues': False, u'is_fork': False, u'slug': u'test', u'is_private': True, u'name': u'test', u'language': u'', u'utc_last_updated': u'2018-05-26 03:47:37+00:00', u'no_public_forks': True, u'creator': None, u'resource_uri': u'/1.0/repositories/hari11/test'}])
```

Also it is not working

```
bb.get_branches()
(False, 'Service not found.')
```

Can you plese help me

Comment: According to the sources, you have a 4xx HTTP error.

Comment: I can only able to access while doing bb.repository.all().. It gave me all repositores

Comment: Also I am not able to archieve it using bb.repository.archive()

Comment: provide the exact repository name and you should be able to get the repository.

Comment: I gave thats why I got response of all but not for individual and some other please read before comment

Comment: Since your `test` repository is private, don't forget to add the password